# Reuse a config variable of package.json in npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

Is it posible to reuse a variable of the config section?

```json
...
"config": {
   "source": "Hello",
   "root": "$npm_package_config_source World"
}
...
```

I can do this in the `scripts` section but I don't know if it is possible in the `config` section or there is one approach to have incremental variables in order to avoid copy & paste...

Comment: It's not possible to reference a config var from inside the `config` object in the way that you are describing. You can only reference them from inside the `scripts` section of _package.json_. So if your `config` object is defined something like this: `"config": {"source": "Hello", "root": "World"}` and in your `scripts` section you have something like this: `"scripts": { "say-hello": "echo $npm_package_config_source $npm_package_config_root"}` - then running `npm run say-hello` will successfully log _Hello World_ to your console.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can "reuse a variable" because there're not quite a variable. JSON files use `key = value` data, so every key have an unique value (or function). If you "reuse" any of the keys, you would overwrite the 'older' key/value.